# Python send to Twilio websocket in x-audio/mulaw 8kHz

Tags: python, twilio

I am trying to send media back to twilio websocket but twilio is not playing the audio, I am using gTTS for text to speach.

Here is my code for text to speach

```
def text_to_mp3(self, f_path :str , f_key: str, text: str) -> str:
        tmp_fn = os.path.join(f_path, f_key + ".mp3"))
        tts = gTTS(text, lang="en")
        tts.save(tmp_fn) #save mp3
        new_fn = os.path.join(f_path, f_key + ".wav")
        audio = am.from_mp3(tmp_fn) #convert mp3 to wav 
        audio = audio.set_channels(1)  # Mono audio
        audio = audio.set_frame_rate(8000)  # 8000Hz sample rate
        audio.export(new_fn, format='wav')
        return new_fn
```

Then when sending the audio I take that file and skip the wav header

```
    def get_encoded_payload(self, filename):
        with wave.open(filename, 'rb') as wav_in:
            params = wav_in.getparams()
            header_size = params.nframes * params.sampwidth + 44 # 44 is the size of the WAV header
            wav_in.readframes(header_size)
            audio_data = wav_in.readframes(params.nframes)
        base64_encoded_audio = base64.b64encode(audio_data).decode()
        return base64_encoded_audio
```

And lastly I sent the audio in twilio stream

```
    def play(self, base_data : str):
        media_data = {
            "event": "media",
            "streamSid": self.streamId,
            "media": {
                "payload": base_data
                }
            }
        self.ws.send(media_data)
```

I am also sending mark message after sending media

```
   def play_mark(self, unique_name: str):
        media_data = {
            "event": "mark",
            "streamSid": self.streamId,
            "mark": {
                "name": unique_name
                }
            }
        self.ws.send(media_data)
```

I am not sure what I am missing. The audio file is in single channel 8khz.

Edit I did tried audio/x-mulaw encoding and still nothing. now my get_encode_payload looks like :

```
    def get_encoded_payload(self, filename):
        with wave.open(filename, 'rb') as wav_in:
            params = wav_in.getparams()
            header_size = params.nframes * params.sampwidth + 44 # 44 is the size of the WAV header
            wav_in.readframes(header_size)
            audio_data = wav_in.readframes(params.nframes)
            ulaw_audio_data= audioop.lin2ulaw(audio_data, params.sampwidth)
        base64_encoded_audio = base64.b64encode(ulaw_audio_data).decode()
        return base64_encoded_audio
```

Answer (score 0):

I am able to fix this , I just had to read the frames and change it to ulaw audio format. Now my function to get encoded text look like this.

```
def get_encoded_payload(self, filename):
    with wave.open(filename, "rb") as wav:  
        raw_wav= wav.readframes(wav.getnframes())   
        raw_ulaw = audioop.lin2ulaw(raw_wav,wav.getsampwidth())
        return base64.b64encode(raw_ulaw).decode("utf-8")
```